# Five cards dealt off of a $52$ card deck

Tags: combinatorics

Five cards are dealt off of a standard $52$-card deck and lined up in a row. How many such line-ups are there in which all $5$ cards are of the same suit?

With $13$ cards per suit and $5$ cards being picked, we can use $\begin{align} {n \choose k} = &\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!} \end{align}$ because we are determining the number of subsets that can be made by choosing 5 elements from a set of 13 elements.

$\begin{align} {13 \choose 5} = \frac{13!}{8!5!} = \frac{13\cdot12\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9}{5!} = 1287 \end{align}$

4 suits in total, so: $1287\cdot4 = 5184$

Is this the correct way to do the problem?

Comment: Almost fine. Except that they are asking about **lineups**, so order matters, and the answer is $(4)(13)(12)(11)(10)(9)$.

Comment: So everything but the $5!$?

Comment: That's right, you had it except you were counting the number of **hands**.

Comment: You are welcome. Counting and probability problems can be very sensitive to exact wording.